# Renaming dataframes in R after read in via loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in a bunch of .tsv files from a folder ('Test'), and I got this far:

```
files <- list.files("Test", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(files[i], read.delim(files[i], na.strings = c(
"FAILED", "ERROR"))
)
```

This works, however the data frames it creates includes the file path and extension (in this case `Test/` and `.tsv` resulting in a data frame named `Test/100_1.tsv`). I've been playing around with the code for a few hours trying to get it to name each data frame by the necessary information only (e.g., `100_1`). If anyone has any suggestions, this novice would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: create a new variable for the assign function like `fnames <- sub(".*(?<=\\/)(.*)(?=\\.tsv).*", "\\1", files, perl=T)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest loading these as a list, rather than into the global namespace with `assign`.

Something like

```
files <- list.files("Test", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE)
names(files) <- files
all.data <- lapply(files, function(fle) {
  read.delim(fle, na.strings=c("FAILED", "ERROR"))
})
```

will yield a list keyed by filename, which will be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a label object that contains the names you would like to apply to your dataframes. The label object I made assumes you always have the same size names. Should do what you are looking for though.

```
files <- list.files("Test", pattern="*.tsv", full.names=TRUE)
dflabels <- substr(files,5,nchar(files)-4)

for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(dflabels[i], read.delim(files[i], na.strings = c(
"FAILED", "ERROR"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get `100_1.tsv` all you need to do is set `full.names = FALSE` and preset your working directory rather than call it in `list.files`.

E.g.

```
setwd("C:/Your/Working/Directory/Test")    
files <- list.files(pattern="*.tsv")
for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(files[i], read.delim(files[i], na.strings = c(
"FAILED", "ERROR"))
)
```

`full.names` defaults to `FALSE`.